# Scala fast way to parallelize collection

Tags: scala, parallel-processing

My code is equivalent to this:

```
def iterate(prev: Vector[Int], acc: Int): Vector[Int] = {
  val next = (for { i <- 1.to(1000000) }
    yield (prev(Random.nextInt(i))) ).toVector

  if (acc < 20) iterate(next, acc + 1)
  else next
}
iterate(1.to(1000000).toVector, 1)
```

For a large number of iterations, it does an operation on a collection, and yields the value. At the end of the iterations, it converts everything to a vector. Finally, it proceeds to the next recursive self-call, but it cannot proceed until it has all the iterations done. The number of the recursive self-calls is very small.

I want to paralellize this, so I tried to use `.par` on the 1.to(1000000) range. This used 8 processes instead of 1, and the result was only twice faster! `.toParArray` was only slightly faster than `.par`. I was told it could be much faster if I used something different, like maybe ThreadPool - this makes sense, because all of the time is spent in constructing `next`, and I assume that concatenating the outputs of different processes onto shared memory will not result in huge slowdowns, even for very large outputs (this is a key assumption and it might be wrong). How can I do it? If you provide code, paralellizing the code I gave will be sufficient.

Note that the code I gave is not my actual code. My actual code is much more long and complex (Held-Karp algorithm for TSP with constraints, BitSets and more stuff), and the only notable difference is that in my code, `prev`'s type is `ParMap`, instead of `Vector`.

Edit, extra information: the ParMap has 350k elements on the worst iteration at the biggest sample size I can handle, and otherwise it's typically 5k-200k (that varies on a log scale). If it inherently needs a lot of time to concatenate the results from the processes into one single process (I assume this is what's happening), then there is nothing much I can do, but I rather doubt this is the case.

Comment: It's not really easy to know what went wrong with `par` here. `par` does indeed have overhead, and it is not the number of elements that matters - most of the overhead is per element, so you pay just as much proportionally with small collections as large ones. The amount of work you are doing per element does factor in. If the amount of work you are doing per element is very small, the overhead is proportionally higher, and `par` may make things worse. When you do large amounts of work per element (more likely with a smaller collection) `par` is more likely to be beneficial.

Comment: The problem may also be with your implementation itself. If you interact with a mutable data structure you could have a false sharing problem (or a true sharing problem!). If you touch anything with locks your code won't really run in parallel. What was your CPU usage? Did the code peg all cores of your computer, or was there still a lot of idle time?

Comment: I based it on this: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/performance.html

The CPU usage is 65-90% per CPU. 

All I interact with is the shared `ParMap`, and it is immutable. My concern is that at the end of the iteration, it takes too much time to concatenate the outputs from all the different processes into one big ParMap. I edited in information about the sample sizes at my post.

Comment: It could very well be that the concatenation of results is what is making it now parallelize well. You could try using a mutable hashtable instead, but then you might get stuck blocking. If you can rework it to be several mutable hashtables, and each thread is only responsible for writing to one of them, you could get good performance.

Comment: I thought of that, but each thread needs random access to the whole hashtable. Otherwise I wouldn't have to wait for an iteration to complete before doing the next iteration.

Comment: Have the hashtables from the previous iteration available to all threads, but read-only. Have the writes done to new hashtables. If you can find a way to swap the two sets at the end of each loop you may be able to mitigate some of the cost of allocation.

Answer (score 0):

Implemented few versions after the original, proposed in the question,

- `rec0` is the original with a for loop;
- `rec1` uses `par.map` instead of for loop;
- `rec2` follows `rec1` yet it employs parallel collection `ParArray` for *[lazy builders (and fast access on bulk traversal operations)](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.4/index.html#scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray)*;
- `rec3` is a non-idiomatic non-parallel version with mutable `ArrayBuffer`.

Thus

```
import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer
import scala.collection.parallel.mutable.ParArray
import scala.util.Random

// Original
def rec0() = {
  def iterate(prev: Vector[Int], acc: Int): Vector[Int] = {
    val next = (for { i <- 1.to(1000000) }
      yield (prev(Random.nextInt(i))) ).toVector

    if (acc < 20) iterate(next, acc + 1)
    else next
  }
  iterate(1.to(1000000).toVector, 1)
}

//  par map
def rec1() = {
  def iterate(prev: Vector[Int], acc: Int): Vector[Int] = {
    val next = (1 to 1000000).par.map { i => prev(Random.nextInt(i)) }.toVector

    if (acc < 20) iterate(next, acc + 1)
    else next
  }
  iterate(1.to(1000000).toVector, 1)
}

// ParArray par map
def rec2() = {
  def iterate(prev: ParArray[Int], acc: Int): ParArray[Int] = {
    val next = (1 to 1000000).par.map { i => prev(Random.nextInt(i)) }.toParArray

    if (acc < 20) iterate(next, acc + 1)
    else next
  }
  iterate((1 to 1000000).toParArray, 1).toVector
}

// Non-idiomatic non-parallel
def rec3() = {
  def iterate(prev: ArrayBuffer[Int], acc: Int): ArrayBuffer[Int] = {

    var next = ArrayBuffer.tabulate(1000000){i => i+1}
    var i = 0
    while (i < 1000000) {
      next(i) = prev(Random.nextInt(i+1))
      i = i + 1
    }

    if (acc < 20) iterate(next, acc + 1)
    else next
  }
  iterate(ArrayBuffer.tabulate(1000000){i => i+1}, 1).toVector
}
```

Then a little testing on averaging elapsed times,

```
def elapsed[A] (f: => A): Double = {
  val start = System.nanoTime()
  f
  val stop = System.nanoTime()
  (stop-start)*1e-6d
}

val times = 10
val e0 = (1 to times).map { i => elapsed(rec0) }.sum / times
val e1 = (1 to times).map { i => elapsed(rec1) }.sum / times
val e2 = (1 to times).map { i => elapsed(rec2) }.sum / times
val e3 = (1 to times).map { i => elapsed(rec3) }.sum / times

// time in ms.
e0: Double = 2782.341
e1: Double = 2454.828
e2: Double = 3455.976
e3: Double = 1275.876
```

shows that the non-idiomatic non-parallel version proves the fastest in average. Perhaps for larger input data, the parallel, idiomatic versions may be beneficial.